# Call a method that return a list of employee from Class Library to UI DataGridView project C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Im new in Entity Framework and LINQ
I have two project one is my class library the other one is my UI project
I'm struggling to show a list of employee from method that return the list from my class library
This is my class:

```
    public static class ViewEmployeesDataManager
    {
        public static List<Employee> ViewManagerEmployees()
        {
            using (var context = new HRSystemContext())
            {
                var query = from empolyee in context.Employees
                            select new { 
                                Name = empolyee.FullName,
                                JobTitle = empolyee.JobTitle,
                                Mobile = empolyee.Mobile};

                return query.ToList();
```

this is how I call it in my form:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=ViewEmployeesDataManager.ViewManagerEmployees();
```

I got this error

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name, string JobTitle, string Mobile>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataAccessLayer.Employee>
```

anyone can help please

Comment: _select new {...}_ creates instances of an anonymous class with those properties, not instances of an Employee class. So you need to be specific on the type created by new (_select new Employee { ...}_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
I solved the error by adding Object instead of Employee in my list
and it's worked

```
public static List<Object> ShowingEmployeeInfo()
    {
        using (var context = new HRSystemContext())
        {
            var employee = from row in context.Employees
                            where row.Username == EmployeeDataManager.currentUser
                            select new {
                                Id = row.Id,
                                Name = row.FullName,
                                Job = row.JobTitle,
                                Mobile = row.Mobile,
                                Manager = row.Manager.FullName
                            };
            return employee.ToList<Object>();

        }
    }
```